# how to get latest text file after searching all drive of a computer

Tags: c#, file

I am trying to get the latest text file in my computer.
I need to go to each each drive of computer and searching for all the text file and need to get only one file which is latest.

I tried some code, getting one error and also not sure latest file from all of the drive will work or not

```
try
        {
            foreach (DriveInfo d in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
            {
                var X = GetLatestFiles(d.Name, "*.txt");

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex); }


public static FileInfo GetLatestFiles(string path, string searchPattern)
    {
        return Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, searchPattern).Union(
            Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path).SelectMany(d =>
            {
                try
                {
                    return GetLatestFiles(d, searchPattern);
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                {
                    return Enumerable.Empty<String>();
                }
            })).OrderByDescending(f => (f == null ? DateTime.MinValue : f.LastWriteTime)).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Error

> The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.SelectMany(IEnumerable, Func>)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.   ConsoleApp1 C:\Users\H190733\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs    43  Active

Comment: Holy moly, that's gonna use a lot of memory. I wouldn't bother using LINQ for this, maybe not recursion either. Have a list of directories you need to process and a FileInfo variable, in each folder you list the contents of, add the folders to the end of the list, then list all the files and find the highest dates fileinfo in the folder and if it's date is more recent than the fileinfo variable outside your processing loop, make the new fileinfo the one to compare to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think (and this is really hard to test on an iPhone, sorry) that if you

```
return (FileInfo)null;
```

Instead of

```
return Enumerable.Empty<String>();
```

Then the error will go away.

You might have to call `.SelectMany<FileInfo>` also. My comment stands; this is a terrible way to search your entire drive. Converting the following pseudocode to c# would be my recommendation:

```
//declare list<directoryinfo> dirs 
//declare FileInfo latestText

//load all drives into the dirs list

//loop over the list with "while the list has more entries" type loop
while(dirs.Count>0){
  // load all the directories in dirs[0] onto the end of the list

  //For each fileinfo in dirs[0] if the create time 
  //is more recent than latestText createTime,
  //set latestText to that fileinfo 

  //remove first entry from dirs 

}
```

The "keep adding to the end of a list of dirs as you search through dirs will be. a lot easier to debug too

Answer (score 0):

```
        FileInfo newestTextFile = null;
        foreach (DriveInfo d in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
        {
            var root = d.RootDirectory;
            var files = root.EnumerateFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            forearch (var file in files)
            {
               if (newestTextFile == null || file.LastAccessTime > newestTextFile.LastAccessTime)
               {
                  newestTextFile = file;
               }
            }
        }
```